# Using result_type with pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) that I created, and return for each row a list of values, where each value is a column in itself.

I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_list(row):
  return [i for i in range(5)]

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(100), columns=['col'])


df.apply(lambda row: get_list(row), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

When I add `result_type='expand'` in order to change the returned array into separate columns I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ("<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'result_type'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

However if  I drop the `result_type` field it runs fine (returns a column of arrays), what might be the problem?

- I'm using [colab](https://colab.research.google.com) to run my code

Comment: this code works for me in pandas version 0.23.3

Comment: For people with a recent version of pandas which have this problem: make sure you are using `df.apply()` not `df.groupby.apply()` because the groupby apply function does not support `expand_result` yet: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html

Comment: You may also see this when you're running apply on a Series. From the documentation for 1.4.2: result_type ... These only act when axis=1 (columns) https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: @Frank_Coumans Series.apply doesn't have axis or result_type; the correct link is https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This code works in pandas version 0.23.3, properly you just need to run `pip install --upgrade pandas` in your terminal.

**Or**

You can accomplish it without the `result_type` as follows:

```
def get_list(row):
    return pd.Series([i for i in range(5)])

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(100), columns=['col'])
pd.concat([df, df.apply(get_list, axis=1)], axis=1)

    col 0   1   2   3   4
0   0   0   1   2   3   4
1   0   0   1   2   3   4
2   0   0   1   2   3   4
3   0   0   1   2   3   4
4   0   0   1   2   3   4
...
```

BTW, you don't need a `lambda` for it, you can just:

```
df.apply(get_list, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

**Update**
The result_type was announced in the release notes of pandas 0.23: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0230 so I am afraid you will have to update.

Comment: What if OP can't upgrade their module?

Comment: I added an alternative, but the `result_type` was rolled out in 0.23

Comment: I tried the code you wrote, it adds a column where each value is an array, it did not add each value in the array to a separate column

Comment: I changed the function of get_list to return a `pd.Series`, did you check that?

Comment: The output is only 5 rows, I was expecting it to add 5 columns to all of the 100 rows

Comment: I only displayed five rows..the function gets applied on all rows.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it met your inquiry.